# Obtaining a .jar from a .exe

Tags: java, windows, jar, exe, decompiler

What I'm currently dealing with is a Windows .exe that contains an executable .jar. I've tried running it through various .exe and .jar decompilers to no avail. My question is, how would I go about obtaining the .jar in the state it was in prior to being shorved into a .exe?

Please be aware, I'm not trying to convert a program from C++ or C# to java, but a .jar packed into an .exe back into a raw .jar.

Comment: ***HOW*** was it placed into an exe? By using what tool? Without knowing this, this may be an unanswerable question. OTOH, it may be unanswerable even if you did know this.

Comment: the solution depends how it get wrapped up inside the exe file in the first place. if you don't know then your best bet is resource hacker tools, http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/ (this one is no longer maintained but it used to work for me)

Comment: You could try using something like 7Zip to unzip the file, no guarantee that it will work

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Unfortunately I don't know how the jar was wrapped.

Comment: Then you may very well be SOL. Sorry.

Comment: You should avoid all of this hard work by asking the people / company who provided you with the ".exe" to give you access to the JAR or the source code.

Comment: Better yet, why do you need a Jar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing any information about how it was packaged into an exe, one way would be to replace the core `ClassLoader` in rt.jar and write the data to a file in its `defineClass` method. This way, whenever the classes are loaded, they will be written to respective files.

Note that this is a hack and has a ton of pitfalls. To name one, it won't include other data in jar files such as resources. Your best bet would be to find out how it was packaged like @HovercraftFullOfEels mentioned.

OpenJDK java.lang.ClassLoader [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/ClassLoader.java)